# Navigation in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, navigation, silverlight-5.0

I want to navigate to new page on the click event of Next button. Suppose my current page is "FirstTestPage.xaml" and want to go on the page "SecondTestPage.xaml" on click on nextButton_Click Event

```
private void RadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ///CODE HERE
}
```

And also want the back button which transfer me to FirstTestPage.xaml.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see my answer to the question: [Making a Wizard in Silverlight + Xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654599/making-a-wizard-in-silverlight-xaml/10656222#10656222)

to quote it: "I would suggest looking into the Silverlight Navigation Framework. It allows you to use "urls" to navigate between "pages" (which are your XAML user controls). It also also users to use the back and forth buttons in the browser, which may or may not be something you want to allow.

There is a VS 2010 template when you choose New Project, Silverlight, "Silverlight Navigation Application" that will help get you started."

You can also use a border or panel in the Xaml and change the content of that. Here's an example using border.
XAML

```
<Grid>
  <Border x:Name="contentBorder" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void RadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  this.contentBorder.Child = new SecondTestPage();
}
```

If you want to get fancy and have the Telerik controls (which I assume from your RadButton example) check out their transition control: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TransitionControl/FirstLook

Comment: I was not able to get "Child" property....instead of that im getting "Children" property

Comment: Border has Child (which is what I use in this example), but Panel has Children. You must be using panel? Either Border or Panel would work, but Border is a bit easier as you don't have to clear out the Children first.